# Ignore all folders but one

Tags: git, gitignore

I read many posts from StackOverflow about this, but I can't get it working in my case.

I would like to ignore all directories except for one.
I added something like this to my .gitignore:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/
!app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/
```

but it looks like the negation doesn't work at all.

There are many subfolders under the path `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/`, and within the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule` folder there are some files if it makes any difference.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the whitelist item on top of the ignore item:

```
!app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/
```

If that still doesn't work, you may have to include the `template` directory itself, but ignore all files beneath it except `mymodule`:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/*
!app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/
```

For more information, see the [gitignore man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).